# how to search in language and get results for another language

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
product

|----|---------------------|
| id |        code         |
|----|---------------------|
|  1 |          A          |
|  2 |          B          |
```

and

```
product_tarnslation
|---|------|---------------------|
|pid| name |        locale       |
|---|------|---------------------|
| 1 |prod A|          en         |
| 2 |prod B|          en         |
| 1 | منتج |          ar         |
| 2 |prod B|          ar         |
```

I need a query to search in any locale but get result for an only desired locale.
eg:
when I search by `prod` and I want `Arabic` translation

```
expected result
|---|------|---------------------|
|pid| name |        locale       |
|---|------|---------------------|
| 1 | منتج |          ar         |
| 2 |prod B|          ar         |
```

UPDATE
I solved it by self join, but it resulted in a slow query.

```
SELECT t1.name as t1name, t2.name as t2name, t1.locale as t1locale, t2.locale as t2locale
FROM product_translation t1
INNER JOIN product_translation t2
on t1.translatable_id = t2.translatable_id
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%prod%'
AND t2.locale = 'ar'
```

Comment: Post ddl including indexes, t1. locale = 'en' will probably help. Also, do you need wildcard at the beginning of prod?

Comment: What does `code` have to do with anything?  If `pid` is "product id", why is product 1 linked product 2?

Comment: Please post TEXT RESULTS of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t1.name as t1name, t2.name as t2name, t1.locale as t1locale, t2.locale as t2locale
FROM product_translation t1
INNER JOIN product_translation t2
on t1.translatable_id = t2.translatable_id
WHERE t1.name LIKE '%prod%'
AND t2.locale = 'ar';   so we can see what the OPTIMIZER is considering doing with your query.